# Why is my date validation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My name, e-mail and check boxes follow the same js pattern and the validation works great but birthday will not validate. I start by stripping the white space so they can't leave it blank, then using a regex to determine if its valid.  Is my regex wrong?

```
validate: function (attrs, options) 
{
    var errors = [],
    pattern = '/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/',
    isValidBirthday = attrs.birthday && attrs.birthday.replace(/\s/g, '') && attrs.birthday === ('pattern');

    if (!isValidBirthday) 
    {
        errors.push(
        {
            "birthday": "Must have a valid birth date."
        });
    }

    if (errors.length) 
    {
        return errors;
    }
},
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in the browser console?

Comment: You have a comma at the end of your `isValidBirthday` line

Comment: That's because I have other variables after it. I end the last variable with a ; but I'll fix it on here.

Comment: Why are you throwing `$`s in your JavaScript code randomly?

Comment: Just copied over from an attempt to use jQuery earlier. Will change.

Comment: @JackWilliams, no I am not getting console errors. I am using backbone, the rest of my validation works if I comment out the birth date part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the regular expression wrong. Try the following instead, noting the lack of
`''` around the regex, and the use of `.test` method on the pattern.

```
var errors = [],
    pattern = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\d\d$/,
    isValidBirthday,
    cleanedBirthday;

cleanedBirthday = attrs.birthday && attrs.birthday.replace(/\s/g, '');
isValidBirthday = pattern.test(cleanedBirthday)
```